# Если все свойства и их значения у объектов одинаковы, то одинаковы ли объекты?

Tags: javascript, объекты

Извините за наверное глупый вопрос. Не буду вставлять весь код. Вопрос небольшой по фрагменту этому, а то я немного засомневался. `greed` это массив с объектами и некоторые из них могут быть с абсолютно одинаковыми свойствами и их значениями. При этом условии все ли они попадут в `acted`? Будет ли интерпретатор воспринимать их как разные объекты?

```
World.prototype.turn = function() {
  var acted = [];
  this.grid.forEach(function(critter, vector) {
    if (critter.act && acted.indexOf(critter) == -1) {
      acted.push(critter);
      this.letAct(critter, vector);
    }
  }, this);
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно это будут разные объекты.

```js
var src = [
  {d: 5},
  {d: 5},
  {d: 5}
]
var dst = [];
for (i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
  if (dst.indexOf(src[i]) == -1)
    dst.push(src[i]);
};
console.log(dst);
```

При сравнении объектов сравниваются их "указатели". Если нужно сравнивать свойства, то нужно писать свой компаратор